# SQL View to create multiple rows

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-view

I need help with a SQL view that I need to create to display data from one table as multiple rows in the view. I hope I get my terminology correct as I am battling to find info on the web as I dont know what to search for.

My issue is that I have data coming from a Wordpress site and I need to display the data in a FileMaker table. The table that holds the data in Wordpress is for an input form that my webdev has created using Gravity Forms. On the screen there are a number of fields that have set field_numbers which store the data row for row.

I was able to create a view to display the header information, but to get the lines information out is a bit tricky. The SQL view for the header information was,

```
    Create VIEW InvD AS 
    SELECT Lead_ID
      MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 THEN Value END) Inv
      MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 6 THEN VALUE END) InvDate
      MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 5 THEN VALUE END) PoNo
      MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 7 THEN VALUE END) DueDate
      MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 17 THEN VALUE END) InvStatus
   FROM wp_rg_lead_detail
   GROUP BY Lead_ID
```

This has been able to get me a table with all the invoice header information from the wp_rg_lead_detail table. Now for the lines, the information is stored in groups and we have 5 lines maximum for the input which is made up of 6 different fields. The structure is;

```
Form name:            field_number: (these are the field numbers for lines 1-5)

Item Discription      18, 34, 40, 51, 59
Quantity              21, 35, 41, 52, 60   
Item Price            22, 36, 42, 53, 61
Vat Item              24, 37, 43, 54, 62
Total                 31, 39, 45, 56, 64
Comment               65, 66, 67, 68, 69
```

I need to get the view to display the data in a lines table similar to this;

[Invoice Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6NVK.png)

Im not to sure how to generate the VIEW statement to get this table view going. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use join.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working using UNION ALL